# How to delete all my progress in Fruit Ninja?

Tags: icloud, ios-appstore, games

I would like to reset all my progress, achievements and objects from **Fruit Ninja**. I've tried deleting it and then reinstalling it again, but I still have all my stuff.

So, how could I reset the game so that it's like I've never played before?

Comment: So you basically you want to start over?

Comment: Yeah :/ basically

Comment: did you enable the HalfBrick account? You could do a factory reset which removes all progress from your device.

Comment: I dont have a halfbrick account. Does that matter? Also, a factory reset might be troublesome. :/ like really troublesome

Comment: ...don't login to game center?

Comment: Don't answer your own question in the question — write it in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When deleting the app, you are prompted if you want to remove the app data from Game Center.

[image]

Choosing Remove will remove this data and subsequently reinstalling the app will start a fresh container for the app data.

Comment: I tried this as well as downloading the game when I wasn't logged into game center. It doesnt seem to work. I might try a reset :(

Comment: Won't that just remove it from being seen in Game Center?

Comment: @TreScaggs No, games can store a variety of key-value pairs besides public leaderboards in Game Center.